# Firestore Storage Not Formatting URL Correctly - CORS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cors

Day 3 now and I cannot seem to solve this error. I cannot solve this no matter what I try, it seems. I'm a newbie web developer. Here's my tech stack:

**ReactJS
NextJS
Vercel
Firebase**

I'm using **VSCode**.

Rules are set to `read write if true` on Firebase. Environment variables on Vercel match those in my `.env.local` file. Storage bucket is the same in console as it is in my `.env.local` file, my `firebase/client.js`, aka,

`storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET`.

No difference. I can upload images fine via localhost, but not via my Vercel link `https://myapp.vercel`.

The forward slash was no help either: `https://myapp.vercel/`.

**Header**

```
Request URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gs%3A%2F%2Fmyapp-ae345.appspot.com%0A/o?name=profileImages%2FdaddaVp0XaeJUQHCVREfr1aP5893
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Authorization: Firebase eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImU3OTMwMjdkYWI0YzcwNmQ2ODg0NGI4MDk2ZTBlYzQzMjYyMjIwMDAiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.Uwmfkp6Q8aMmUjejqsWLHFkLdJNkEnvcMZ8tb-xJkDk4wF3e_tXrryEXmsMOY_M_HSZxyUSZtFXBDHJseMm8OXOTPVJgAqlPNTshxL_Hf5l9zYMF7pFwhvNDWTEzsck1sh5jdqQii1kwaQncf8KB0mbUWxOe0-x2r0_S-h4l8L5EpZMXsRxHcaKrQq8h2WX3QQUVFYMyxijpGjBya866fCDUnpcqP-Q6dV0tU69mwOm3dsyskuOJ2dHKbKf8yGZVPjGgsSHOMkVPkdS2apiZC5og_TVzrBOO4bYrWAP5K7CKVKTHhAmNavRy0d7KP5FVPvG0JM4Qo8t4qFK4MI7TMA
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=73063316883097577124847251768784
Referer: https://myapp.vercel.app/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Brave";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Firebase-Storage-Version: webjs/9.19.1
X-Goog-Upload-Protocol: multipart
```

**Payload**

```
name: profileImages%2FdaddaVp0XaeJUQHCVREfr1aP5893
--73063316883097577124847251768784
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"name":"profileImages/daddaVp0XaeJUQHCVREfr1aP5893","contentType":"image/jpeg"}
--73063316883097577124847251768784
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

I can authenticate the user, but when I go to create the profile in my `profile.js`, I get stuck loading on `home.js` where the created user and their data should appear.

Here's the console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gs%3A%2F%2Fmyapp-ae345.appspot.com%0A/o?name=profileImages%2FvdqRy684hBTukzTBvIHVpdVTyCr1' from origin 'https://myapp.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gs%3A%2F%2Fmyapp-ae345.appspot.com%0A/o?name=profileImages%2FvdqRy684hBTukzTBvIHVpdVTyCr1:1     Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Finally, here's how I upload the profile:

```
 const saveUserProfile = async (uid, data, profileImage) => {
    try {
      // Upload the file to Firebase Storage
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `profileImages/${uid}`);
      await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, profileImage);
  
      // Get the download URL from Firebase Storage
      const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
      console.log("Download URL:", downloadURL);
  
      // Save the user profile data
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
      await setDoc(userRef, { ...data, profileImageUrl: downloadURL, website });
  
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving user profile: ", error);
      setError("Error saving user profile. Please try again.");
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Something wrong with the URL, it seems?

Comment: Have you checked that 1 ] the firebase Authorization token passed is correct and not expired 2] Try to give the values directly rather than env file just for debugging purposes to verify that this is not the issue with environmental variables. 3] There is also an updated version of [**firebase storage API**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/storage/rest) which uses v1 so you might also give it a try for that.

Comment: 1.] I'm using Firebase Auth. I can sign-in fine. My email password is one screen 1 and I upload the profile on screen 2. It works. 2.] Environmental variables work, as well. I created test files for them, too. 3.] No luck.